# Getting Fatl Exception in Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very new to Android and i am learning android through "online" from some site.
Now i am learning how to implement **Fragments**.
In that very initially i got below exception and i don't know the reason.Please help me to resolve it.

**Exception::**

```
03-30 17:55:23.583: I/Process(1221): Sending signal. PID: 1221 SIG: 9
03-30 17:55:24.701: E/Trace(1265): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-30 17:55:24.921: D/AndroidRuntime(1265): Shutting down VM
03-30 17:55:24.921: W/dalvikvm(1265): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragments/com.example.fragments.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at com.example.fragments.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     ... 11 more
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.fragments: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4709)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     ... 21 more
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.fragments" on path: /data/app/com.example.fragments-1.apk
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
03-30 17:55:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(1265):     ... 24 more
```

**MainActivity .java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        /**
        * Check the device orientation and act accordingly
        */
        if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
           /**
           * Landscape mode of the device
           */
            LM_Fragement ls_fragment = new LM_Fragement();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, ls_fragment);
        }else{
           /**
           * Portrait mode of the device
           */
            PM_Fragement pm_fragment = new PM_Fragement();
           fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, pm_fragment);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**PM_Fragement.Java**

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PM_Fragement extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
              ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              /**
               * Inflate the layout for this fragment
               */
              return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.pm_fragment, container, false);
           }
}
```

**AndroidManifet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fragments"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fragments.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".PM_Fragement" />
        <activity android:name=".LM_Fragement"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**LM_Fragement.java **

```
package com.example.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class LM_Fragement extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
              ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              /**
               * Inflate the layout for this fragment
               */
              return inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.lm_fragment, container, false);
           }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the import statements of   `PM_Fragement`

Comment: added at below code of PM_Fragement.java

Comment: Start by reading the *inner most* cause first: **Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: *Didn't find class "com.example.fragments"* on path: /data/app/com.example.fragments-2.apk** - whoops! Did you forget a *class name* in the manifest?

Comment: Sorry din't look at the full stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Remove these form manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".PM_Fragement" />
<activity android:name=".LM_Fragement"/>
```

`PM_Fragement` and `LM_Fragement` are `Fragments` not Activities. Only Activities are declared in manifest file.

Comment: still same problem. Getting exception

Comment: @user3478658 make the changes re-run and post the stacktrace again

Comment: @user3478658 and do post `LM_Fragement` with imports

Comment: new stacktrace and LM_Fragment added

Comment: @user3478658 looks alright to me unless i am missing something

Comment: Yes Raghu... but i am unable to launch... And i am trying to launch on API lvl17 AVD

Comment: @Krishna does not matter on what api you want to test. But i don't see anything wrong with the code